# How can I push a prop and its value to objects that don't have that specific property knowing that these objects are in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

what I want to achieve is:-

Loop through the `peopleData` array,
add a `prop` call it `'age'` and give it a value of `'-'`
if one of the objects (array elements)
does not have the key 'age'

```html
const peopleData = [
  { name: "Ann", age: 15, email: "ann@test.com", birthMonth: "Jan" },
  { name: "Bob", age: 19, email: "bob@test.com", birthMonth: "Mar" },
  { name: "Cam", age: 18, email: "cam@test.com", birthMonth: "Feb" },
  { name: "Dan" },
  { name: "Steve", birthMonth: "Jun" },
  { name: "Tyson", age: 20, birthMonth: "Dec" },
];
```

That what I tried to do and it did not work

```
const addAgeObj = {age: '-'}

const myArr = peopleData.map(personData=> {
  if(!personData.age) {
  peopleData.push(addAgeObj);
  console.log(peopleData);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`peopleData.push` is wrong. You need to update the object, not to add new objects to the array.

```js
const peopleData = [
  { name: "Ann", age: 15, email: "ann@test.com", birthMonth: "Jan" },
  { name: "Bob", age: 19, email: "bob@test.com", birthMonth: "Mar" },
  { name: "Cam", age: 18, email: "cam@test.com", birthMonth: "Feb" },
  { name: "Dan" },
  { name: "Steve", birthMonth: "Jun" },
  { name: "Tyson", age: 20, birthMonth: "Dec" },
];

const myArr = peopleData.map(personData=> {
  return {...personData, age: personData.age || '-'}
});

console.log(myArr);
```

Comment: that's exactly how I expect it.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```js
const addAgeObj = {age: '-'}
const peopleData = [
    { name: "Ann", age: 15, email: "ann@test.com", birthMonth: "Jan" },
    { name: "Bob", age: 19, email: "bob@test.com", birthMonth: "Mar" },
    { name: "Cam", age: 18, email: "cam@test.com", birthMonth: "Feb" },
    { name: "Dan" },
    { name: "Steve", birthMonth: "Jun" },
    { name: "Tyson", age: 20, birthMonth: "Dec" },
];
const myArr = peopleData.map(personData=> {
    /* if(!personData.age) {
    peopleData.push(addAgeObj);
    console.log(peopleData); 
    }*/
    if(!Object.keys(personData).includes("age"))
        personData={...personData,addAgeObj}
    return personData
});
console.log(myArr)
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

peopleData.push does is adding new object and override the existing object.So that is wrong and that is not what you want.so try this one.

```
const peopleData = [
  { name: "Ann", age: 15, email: "ann@test.com", birthMonth: "Jan" },
  { name: "Bob", age: 19, email: "bob@test.com", birthMonth: "Mar" },
  { name: "Cam", age: 18, email: "cam@test.com", birthMonth: "Feb" },
  { name: "Dan" },
  { name: "Steve", birthMonth: "Jun" },
  { name: "Tyson", age: 20, birthMonth: "Dec" },
];


const myArr = peopleData.map(personData=> {
  if(!personData.age) {
  
 let newobj={...personData,age:"-"};
  
 return newobj;
  
   }
else{

return personData;

  }
});

console.log(myArr);
```